# cloud sql send pubsub message on update/insert

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-pubsub, graphql-java

I am setting up a read only GraphQL instance using Java. GraphQL as I understand it needs to be told when to re-query its data sources. We are using GCP, and Cloud SQL for our primary data source. Our monolithic system is what is responsible for updating the data.

Is there a way to trigger a web request or pub/sub message from cloud sql without sys_eval(sys_eval('curl https://example.com'));?

or is there a way to turn on sys_eval in cloud sql?

Comment: I'm having some trouble understanding what is your system's architecture like. Could you correct me on the following if I'm wrong? 1) You have a GCE instance with GraphQL installed. 2) You have a Cloud SQL instance containing your data source. 3) You connect through a MySQL client to the Cloud SQL and fetch newly inserted/modified data using 'sys_eval()' 4) You update the GCE instance with said data

Comment: 1 and 2 are correct, 3 is what I'm trying to do. However, it seems that cloud sql does not allow sys_eval so I need another way to notify graphql that there has been a change to the data in the database.

Answer (score 0):

After some brainstorming around sys_eval alternatives such as binary logs and so on, I think the course of action I'd recommend is to move the MySQL client to the GCE instance, and establish the connection to the Cloud SQL instance through a [Private IP](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/private-ip).

Such connection will be guaranteed a much lower latency, and an a lot higher network security, since, the service does not use Public IPs and it would be protected from the "outside" Internet; all compared to your current architecture.

You can find connection examples using VPC networks in the documentation provided.